# Problem in parsing JSON data received through $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

When I use JSON data obtained by:

```
$.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&&start=0&rows=100&q="+elegant+"&hl=true&hl.fl=description&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&json.wrf=?", function(newresult){
```

and use this JSON data as:

```
$.each(newresult.highlighting, function(i, hitem){
        alert(hitem.description[0]);
        
});
```

then I am not getting the description field value.

But when I assign whole data in a variable, say `newresult` and then run `$.each()` it is working, as I did in http://jsfiddle.net/taL8x/1/. Please tell me what is the problem when I use data through `getJSON()`.

Comment: That's a huge example. Could you remove some stuff and make it simpler?

Comment: Also, could you put this on a public port so we could take a look at it live? It could be a problem in the JSON syntax or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If passing line at `alert`, newresult.highlighting should be object or array. then, this is not a problem about Same Origin Policy. And you are specifying `json.wrf=?` for callback.
Probably, you missed about struct of element in highlighting array. maybe.
Try to access directry, and confirm structure of the array.
You are expecting:

```
{
"highlighting": [ { "description" : "foo" }, { "description" : "bar" } ]
}
```

But it may be

```
{
"highlighting": { "A001" : { "description" : "foo" }, "A002" : { "description" : "bar" } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is probably stopped by the Same Origin Policy. If the service is on a different URL, you will have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: Not necessarily. If he has control of the webserver, he could set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the server to "*" and not have to use JSONP. This is part of [Cors](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).